# Dojo DataGrid (DGrid) Adding checkbox column

Tags: javascript, dojo, dgrid

I am using **Dojo** Dgrid however i am trying to add a checkbox column however i am not sure of the approach.

Most of the tutorials i have been looking at follow a different code structure and i am unable to create the check box column. I would like to create a checkbox column to select rows

**Code** (Here is also a [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/devdarin/V2PBm/2/) of my code)

require([
....................... 
     "dojo/domReady!"

```
], function(parser, declare, Grid, ColumnSet, Selection, selector,Keyboard, DijitRegistry){
      parser.parse();

      var data = [
            { first: "Tom", last: "Evans" },
            { first: "Sherry", last: "Young"},
            { first: "Bob", last: "William"}
        ];

      var columns =     [
          [[
              {editor({name: "CheckBox", field: "bool"}, "checkbox")},
              { field: "first", label: "First" },
            { field: "last", label: "Last" }]]
                        ];           

      var CustomGrid = declare([Grid, ColumnSet, Selection, Keyboard, DijitRegistry]);




      var grid = new CustomGrid ({
            columnSets: columns ,
            "class":"grid"
        }, "grid");
     grid.renderArray(data);   
});
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to have a column with checkboxes for the purpose of selecting rows, you should set your sights on the `selector` column plugin rather than `editor`.  `selector` is specifically designed to render checkboxes (or radio buttons) in each cell that ties in to the `Selection` mixin when checked.

See the [documentation in the wiki](https://github.com/SitePen/dgrid/blob/v1.0.0/doc/components/mixins/Selector.md), and the [selector test page](http://dgrid.io/js/dgrid/test/Selector.html).

Comment: can you look at this for me please http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22463142/dojo-dgrid-select-all-option-issue

Comment: On a related topic, how can we set the checkboxes to be dijit/form/CheckBoxes ? The default ones stand out when using a dijit theme because... well... they're not styled.

Comment: @Ken Franqueiro can you assist with this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23635574/dojo-date-constraint

Answer (score 1):

you  can also  test this  solution

first  you must  add  this  Modules  in require([])  section

```
"dgrid/extensions/ColumnResizer",
               "esri/request", "dgrid/OnDemandGrid", "dgrid/Selection", "dojo/store/Memory", "dgrid/selector",
```

then  define  this array  to hold  your  columns

```
 var columnsPol = [];
```

then  add  check box  type  column  to array  and  any other  type column to array

```
 columnsPol.push(
             selector({ label: selector({}), selectorType: "checkbox" })
            );

columnsPol.push({
                label: "",
                field: {any  name},
                formatter: {a  function  for  formatting value  of cell},
                width: "auto",
                });

                .
                .
                .
```

then  define  your Grid  and set properties

```
var gridPol = new (declare([Grid, ColumnResizer, Selection]))({
     store: {your data},
     columns: columnsPol,
     minRowsPerPage: 40,
     maxRowsPerPage: 40,
     keepScrollPosition: true,
     selectionMode: 'none',
     allowSelectAll: true,
     loadingMessage: "Loading data...",
     noDataMessage: "No results found."
 }, {Id  for grid});
 gridPol.refresh();
```

and  then you can get  selected  and deselected  rows

```
 gridPol.on("dgrid-select", function (event) {
           var selectedRows = event.rows;
           });
```

and  deselect

```
 gridPol.on.on("dgrid-deselect",function (event){
            var deselectedRows = event.rows;
            });
```