# Cannot get JSFiddle to run Dojo Wizard

Tags: javascript, jsfiddle, dojo

I am trying to create a [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/devdarin/bmdML/12/) however i am unable to get the code to run. I have loaded the relevant resources and it does not work. I am creating a Dojo form Wizard.

Code :

**Html**

```
 <div dojoType="dojox.widget.WizardPane" id="EmployeeNameWizPane">

                <div data-dojo-type="dojox.layout.TableContainer"
                    data-dojo-props="cols:1,customClass:'employee_labels', labelWidth:180"
                    id="EmployeeNameContainer">

                    <label>1. What Is Your Name ?</label>

                    <s:textfield type="text" required="true" name="surname"
                        id="surname" placeholder="Your SurName"
                        data-dojo-type="dijit/form/ValidationTextBox"
                        missingMessage="Please Enter Your Surname!" title="(a). Surname :" 
                        style="width: 25em;" />


                    <s:textfield type="text" required="true" name="firstname"
                        id="firstname" placeholder="Your FirstName"
                        data-dojo-type="dijit/form/ValidationTextBox"
                        missingMessage="Please Enter Your FirstName!"
                        title="(b). FirstName :" 
                        style="width: 25em;" />

                    <s:textfield type="text" required="false" name="other_names"
                        id="other_names" placeholder="Other Names"
                        data-dojo-type="dijit/form/ValidationTextBox"
                        title="(c). Other Names :" 
                        style="width: 25em;" />

                </div>
            </div> 



            <div dojoType="dojox.widget.WizardPane" id="EmployeeBirthNameWizPane">

                <div data-dojo-type="dojox.layout.TableContainer"
                    data-dojo-props="cols:1,customClass:'employee_labels', labelWidth:180"
                    id="EmployeeBirthNameContainer">
                    <label>2. Is you name on your Birth Certificate is
                        different from (1) above ?(e.g. Changed by Deed Poll / Marriage)</label>

                    <s:textfield type="text" required="true" name="birth_surname"
                        id="birth_surname" placeholder="Your SurName"
                        data-dojo-type="dijit/form/ValidationTextBox"
                        missingMessage="Please Enter Your Surname On Your Birth Certificate!"
                        title="(a). Surname :"
                        style="width: 25em;" />

                    <s:textfield type="text" required="true" name="birth_firstname"
                        id="birth_firstname" placeholder="Your FirstName"
                        data-dojo-type="dijit/form/ValidationTextBox"
                        missingMessage="Please Enter Your FirstName On Your Birth Certificate!"
                        title="(b). FirstName :" 
                        style="width: 25em;"/>

                    <s:textfield type="text" required="false" name="birth_other_names"
                        id="birth_other_names" placeholder="Other Names"
                        data-dojo-type="dijit/form/ValidationTextBox"
                        title="(c). Other Names :"
                        style="width: 25em;" />


                </div>

            </div> 




            <div dojoType="dojox.widget.WizardPane" id= "EmployeeIdWizPane">

                <div data-dojo-type="dojox.layout.TableContainer"
                    data-dojo-props="cols:2,customClass:'employee_labels', labelWidth:250"
                    id="EmployeeIdentificationContainer">

                    <label>3. Please Enter At Least Two Forms Of Identification</label> 

                    <s:select data-dojo-type="dijit/form/FilteringSelect" id="id"
                        name="id" title= "Identification Type"
                        list="#{'':'Select Your I.D Type','1':'Passport','2':'Drivers Permit','3':'Electoral Identification'}"/>

                    <s:textfield type="text" required="true" name="idNumber"
                        id="idNumber" placeholder="Your Identification Number"
                        data-dojo-type="dijit/form/ValidationTextBox"
                        missingMessage="Please Enter Your Identification Number"
                        title="(a). Identification Number :"
                        style="width: 25em;" />         

                </div>
                    <div id="grid" class="grid"></div>

              </div>    

            </div>
```

**Javascript**

```
require([

    "dijit/form/CheckBox",
    "dijit/form/Textarea",
    "dijit/form/FilteringSelect",
    "dijit/form/TextBox",
    "dijit/form/ValidationTextBox",
    "dijit/form/DateTextBox",
    "dijit/form/TimeTextBox",
    "dijit/form/Button",
    "dijit/form/RadioButton",
    "dijit/form/Form",

]);

require([
    "dojox/validate/us",
    "dojox/validate/web",
    "dojox/layout/TableContainer",
    "dojox/layout/GridContainer",
    "dojox/widget/Wizard",
    "dojox/widget/WizardPane",
    "dojox/grid/_CheckBoxSelector"

]);

require([
    "dojo/parser",
    "dojo/_base/declare",
    "dojo/store/Memory",
    "dgrid/OnDemandGrid",
    "dgrid/ColumnSet",
    "dgrid/Selection",
    "dgrid/selector",
    "dgrid/Keyboard",
    "dgrid/extensions/DijitRegistry",
    "dgrid/editor",
    "dgrid/extensions/ColumnHider",


    "dojo/domReady!"

], function (parser, declare, MemoryStore, OnDemandGrid, ColumnSet, Selection, selector, Keyboard, DijitRegistry, editor, ColumnHider) {
    parser.parse();


    var data = [{
        id: "1",
        idType: "Passport",
        idNumber: "12121545WWW"
    }, {
        id: "2",
        idType: "Drivers Permit",
        idNumber: "11212154515 FF"
    }, {
        id: "3",
        idType: "Electoral Identification",
        idNumber: "425123123121"
    }];
    var store = new MemoryStore({
        data: data
    });
    var columns = [
        [
            [{
                label: "Id",
                field: "Id"
            },
            editor({
                label: "",
                field: "select",
                sortable: false,
                autoSave: true
            }, "checkbox"), {
                field: "idType",
                label: "Identification Type"
            }, {
                field: "idNumber",
                label: "Identification Number"
            }]
        ]
    ];

    var CustomGrid = declare([OnDemandGrid, selector, Selection, Keyboard, editor, DijitRegistry, ColumnHider]);




    var grid = new CustomGrid({
        store: store,
        columns: {
            col1: {
                label: "Id",
                field: "Id",
                hidden: true
            },

            selector: selector({
                selectorType: "checkbox"
            }),

            col3: {
                label: "ID Type",
                field: "idType"
            },

            col4: {
                label: "ID Number",
                field: "idNumber"
            }

        },
        SelectionMode: "none",
        allowSelectAll: true
    }, "grid");



    //grid.styleColumn("Id","display:none;");

    grid.renderArray(data);
});
```

Comment: Tons of 404s, that would be why. Does the CDN actually host all of those files?

Comment: @epascarello i updated the jsfiddle. Yes i was able to access all the resources hosted by the CDN

Comment: @epascarello even with the update on the fiddle i am still unable to run the form wizard

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The **dgrid** library is not a part of the Dojo library. You have to manually add that and configure it using `data-dojo-config`. Make sure you read [this article](http://dojofoundation.org/packages/dgrid/tutorials/hello_dgrid/). As you can see there (almost at the top of the article) it says:

> dgrid is one of the first new Dojo packages to be distributed
>   standalone instead of as a part of the DojoX namespace. This
>   distribution model is part of a shift toward a distributed component
>   development model in Dojo 2, made possible by advances in distributed
>   code services like GitHub.

So you will have to add dgrid by yourself. I'm not finding an official CDN hosting dgrid at the moment, so you will have to host it by yourself.

But you could have validated this easily by yourself, like @epascarello said in the comment section, there are 404 errors and all of them are related to dgrid.

Comment: i updated the fiddle and hosted the dgrid files however i am still getting an error i am unable to resolve can you assist?

Comment: You're missing several things. First you have to configure Dojo that it knows that the `dgrid`, `put-selector` and `xstyle` packages are on a different location. If you do that then you will get another error because you're still missing several files. You need more than just the files you added AND they have to be hierarchically correct.  So hosting them on Google drive is not a solution unless you can expose an entire directory structure.

Comment: oh i see whats the best way i can get this to work then?

Comment: would you be able to look at this question for me sone i am trying to replicate the issue in this fiddle to attach to my question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22463142/dojo-dgrid-header-checkbox-to-select-all-does-not-work

Comment: I have no experience with dgrid or the WizardPane, so that would be hard for me to help you. And the best way to make it work on JSFiddle is to use some free hosting and put dgrid/xstyle/put-selector up there.